# Chrome Extension installation "Invalid manifest"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that uploads to the Chrome store just fine. My current manifest file is posted below. It is saved in ANSI format as suggested in previous posts with this issue. This is the third variant and they all produce the same error message when I try to install: "Invalid manifest". No real information. I have tried waiting 24 hours for it to propagate properly as suggested in previous posts, but to no effect.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

The extension is here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bamboo-dialog-fixer/oelecpkhobhmbbdmehaoonkbkdodhdio?hl=en-US

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Bamboo dialog fixer",
  "version": "1.3",
  "description": "This extension makes bamboo popup dialogs such a the performance dialogs fit the width of the screen.",
  "icons": {"128": "BambooHR_FullSize.png"},
  "content_scripts":
  {
    "css": "styles.css",
    "matches": "https://*.bamboohr.co.uk/*"
  }
}
```

Comment: "content_scripts", "css", "matches" keys are arrays, so add `[` and `]` as shown in [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: I thought I'd got it like that in my 1.2 iteration, but I have rewritten and uploaded again, so fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks wOxxOm. I must have screwed up, even though I thought I had it right on a previous occasion. I rewrote the file as below and uploaded and it works now.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Bamboo dialog fixer",
  "version": "1.4",
  "description": "This extension makes bamboo popup dialogs such a the performance dialogs fit the width of the screen.",
  "icons": {"128": "BambooHR_FullSize.png"},
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "matches": ["https://*.bamboohr.co.uk/*"]
  }
  ]
}
```